# Ionic Runtime error when trying to retrieve list from firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I am new to Angular.

I am following a tutorial on [youtube for ionic with firebase.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_73tsvj6OI)

But I am using latest modules as of the time of this post as compared to the tutorial

- node v.8.94
- npm 5.6.0
- cordova@8.0.0
- ionic@3.19.1
- rxjs@5.5.6
- angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.6
- firebase@4.9.0

I encountered an issue as shown in both the screen shot below,
[image: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.]

On run
[image: runtime error]
Before creating this post I tried various solutions suggested in similar post but to no avail. Please help.

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FirebaseService } from './../../providers/firebase-service/firebase-service';
import { AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database/interfaces';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  posts: AngularFireList<any[]>;
  newPost: '';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public firebaseService: FirebaseService) {
    this.posts = this.firebaseService.getPosts();
  }

  addPost() {
    this.firebaseService.addPost(this.newPost);
  }

  removePost(id) {
    this.firebaseService.removePost(id);
  }
}
```

**firebase-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {

  constructor(public afd: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  getPosts() {
    return this.afd.list('/posts/');
  }

  addPost(title) {
    this.afd.list('/posts/').push(title);
  }

  removePost(id) {
    this.afd.list('/posts/').remove(id);
  }
}
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row justify-content-center>
      <ion-col col-8>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newPost" placeholder="New post"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-auto>
        <button ion-button (click)="addPost()">Post!</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
      <ion-item>
        {{ post.$value }}
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options side="right">
        <button ion-button color="danger" icon-only (click)="removePost(post.$key)">
          <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

*UPDATE1:*
Syntax error solved by changing

```
posts: AngularFireList<any[]>;
```

to

```
posts: AngularFireList<{}>;
```

but still getting the same runtime error.

*UPDATE2:*
tried commenting out
    posts: AngularFireList<{}>;

App ran without error. But that's not a solution.

Comment: (Sorry my bad, didn't realize this was 2 issues)

Comment: If you have another question, please ask another question, don't just tack it onto the end of your current, answered, question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it's the same question overall, just updating the question with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better way to do this

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';  
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { FirebaseService } from './../../providers/firebase-service/firebase-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  posts: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public firebaseService: FirebaseService) {
        this.posts = this.firebaseService
  .getPosts() // DB LIST
  .map(changes => {
    return changes.map(c => ({
      key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
    }))
  });
  }
}
```

**firebase-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {
  private postsRef = this.db.list<any>('/posts');

  constructor(public afd: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  getPosts() {
    return this.postsRef.snapshotChanges();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GetPosts from AngularFire returns generic AngularFireList. By defining AngularFireList you are saying that your list elements/items will be of type T. Now since AngularFireList already is enumerable (array like) type, you should define it with:

```
posts: AngularFireList<{}>;
```

This is saying that you are expecting "some" object. It's the same as writing `any`. You were defining it as a list of array (or two dimension array) which is not matching the type AngularFire service returns.

Comment: Changing it to posts: AngularFireList<{}>; solved the syntax error but am getting runtime error on build.

Comment: It's a fairly long error. I've updated the question with a screenshot.

Comment: In your HTML you are somewhere using async pipe, but the Object before pipe is not async. Remove the pipe and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
posts: AngularFireList<{}>;
```